# Google Chart MySQL Results

Tags: mysql, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google charts for displaying the results of my query.
This here is the php part:

```
<?php

include('db.php');

$mysqli = SQLConnect();
$myArray = array();

$sql = "select id, rating from ratings order by RateDate DESC limit 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

And this is the actual part where I try to use it:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});    
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

  function drawChart1() {

    var options = {
      title: 'Last 5 Ratings',
      height: 400,
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var jsonData = $.post({

      url: '../resources/db/getDataForChart1.php',
      dataType:"json",
      async: false,
      success: function(jsonData){
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('lastEvaluations'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    }).responseText;
  }
```

As an error of the arrayToDatabaseTable function I get:

```
Uncaught Error: First row is not an array.
```

Which supposedly means that the array fetched by the php script is malformed, but looking at their docs I do not get what is wrong with it.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is most likely coming across as an object `{}`, instead of an array `[]`

in your `while` statement, create a new array and add each value from the result
then add the new array to `$myArray`

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowArray = array();
    $rowArray[] = $row["id"];
    $rowArray[] = $row["rating"];
    $myArray[] = $rowArray;
}
```

also, `arrayToDataTable` expects the first array to be column labels,
unless the second parameter is `true`, meaning first row is data

so, you either need to add column labels...

```
$rowArray = array();
$rowArray[] = "id";
$rowArray[] = "rating";
$myArray[] = $rowArray;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowArray = array();
    $rowArray[] = $row["id"];
    $rowArray[] = $row["rating"];
    $myArray[] = $rowArray;
}
```

or set the second parameter to `true`...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData, true);
```

note: `arrayToDataTable` is a static method, `new` keyword shouldn't be used...